# Regular expressions on converting a URL hex code into character

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, url

I have this sample URL with hex code:

```
http%3a%2f%2fwww.pmi.com%2feng%2fcareers%2fpages%2fjob_details.aspx%3fjlang%3deng%26jcod%3dUS-02073
```

I want to formulate a regular expression on converting those hex code into character entities.

```
%2f => /
```

Is it possible to have transform the link into this using reg expression?

**from:**

```
http%3a%2f%2fwww.pmi.com%2feng%2fcareers%2fpages%2fjob_details.aspx%3fjlang%3deng%26jcod%3dUS-02073
```

**output:**

```
http://www.pmi.com/eng/careers/pages/job_details.aspx?jlang=eng&jcod=US-02073
```

Like the function of this site: http://www.url-encode-decode.com/?_ga=1.244038725.1379940417.1464232194

Comment: use javascript. decodeURIComponent()

Comment: Thanks @sweaver2112 but I only have limited options as well, I am using a software then the only accepted codes is either regular expression, C# and VB.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier done in C# than Regex:

```
using System.Net;

string URL = "http%3a%2f%2fwww.pmi.com%2feng%2fcareers%2fpages%2fjob_details.aspx%3fjlang%3deng%26jcod%3dUS-02073";
string DecodedURL = WebUtility.UrlDecode(URL);
```